# RSA signatures without padding by using XOF output in range [1, n-1]

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature

RSA signatures are implemented by encrypting the padded hash with the private key.

Why not take the approach RSA-KEM is using by removing the padding entirely and replacing the hash with a XOF that would produce the m value in range [1, n-1].

XOF is just a hash with arbitrary output length.

Why hasn't it been done this way?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Can MGF1 within OAEP and PSS be replaced by a XOF?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37766/18298) may be another [Is there an easy way to make textbook RSA secure enough so it can be used in real life?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/95915/18298) and see the search [RSA full domain hash](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=RSA+full+domain+hash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why hasn't it been done this way?

It has been "done" but is sadly not a widely deployed scheme. This scheme is sometimes called [RSA-FDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash): RSA full domain hash. It's a general construction that works with any trapdoor one-way permutation, but so far, we don't have anything as practical as RSA).

Here's [an example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9381.html#name-rsa-full-domain-hash-vrf-rs) of its use in a practical construction, although they don't use an XOF.

This is also a secure scheme in the sense of strong unforgeability, assuming the RSA inversion problem is hard and the hash function "behaves" like a random oracle.

Answer (score 4):

Two preliminary remarks on the question's

> RSA signatures are implemented by encrypting the padded hash with the private key

- The terminology "encrypt with the private key" is improper. That could be e.g. "apply the private-key textbook RSA permutation". At issue is that public key *encryption* is always with the *public* key, because the goal of encryption is to make what's encrypted unintelligible to adversaries (and the public key, which adversaries know, allows to undo the private-key textbook RSA permutation).
- Not all standard RSA signature schemes work in this way, see RSA(SSA)-PSS below.

---

> Why hasn't (RSA signature) been done (with the hash and padding replaced by a XOF)?

That's for historical reasons only:

- RSA signature was standardized long before there was any XOF defined.
- No attack on proper implementation of [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A90%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C721%2Cnull%5D) (hash, pad, apply private-key permutation) was ever found; same for the earlier PKCS#1 signature when applied to a hash (resulting in a [slightly different padding)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/109345/555); or other similar padding schemes, like [ANS X9.31](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37536/555).
- The concept of making a hash (nearly) as wide as the public modulus, as the question considers, is the simplest signature scheme based on a trapdoor permutation (such as textbook RSA) that enjoys a strict security reduction to the RSA problem. It was introduced by Mihir Bellare and Phillip Rogaway: [*The Exact Security of Digital Signatures - How to Sign with RSA and Rabin*](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/exact.pdf#page=8) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 1996](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-68339-9_34)) only after RSA signature got standardized. And that paper gave a security reduction for RSA-FDH requiring a large RSA modulus. It recommended a randomized signature padding (much like in RSA encryption), RSA-PSS, leading to a much tighter security reduction for  common RSA modulus size. Thus RSA-FDH was not standardized, and [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A78%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C314%2Cnull%5D) was added to PKCS#1 in version 2 (and has some level of adoption).
- From a practical perspective, it made no difference that Jean-Sébastien Coron later improved the security argument for RSA-FDH in [*On the Exact Security of Full Domain Hash*](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/fdh.pdf) (in [proceedings of Crypto 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44598-6_14)) and [*Optimal Security Proofs for PSS and Other Signature Schemes*](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/optimal.pdf#page=8) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-46035-7_18)).

Comment: One interesting note on the last point. I believe Coron's impossibility result is generic to any trapdoor permutation, and there are subclasses of trapdoor permutations for which a tight proof is possible. So, it's probably an open question for RSA whether assumptions are reasonable to allow certain RSA parameters to enjoy tight proofs.

Comment: RSA encryption and decryption are identical, IIRC, so "encrypt with private key" is fine, but only for RSA. You can't encrypt with an ED25519 private key, for example.

Comment: @user253751: in _some_ definitions of textbook RSA, encryption and decryption are identical. But even then we do no "encrypt with private key", for we could decrypt with public key, thus anyone could decrypt, which goes against what encryption does. And, in RSA as typically practiced, encryption and decryption differ. 1) For efficiency, decryption often uses the factorization of the modulus, which then is in the decryption/private key. That's never the case for encryption/public key. 2) Encryption/public exponent is typically small (e.g. 65537). Decryption/private exponent is always large.